# How to STOP redirecting my website to mobile.mywebsite.com in smartphones

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mobile, redirect

I have developed a website www.mywebsite.com and it is ready to go live.
I have used Codeigniter framework.

When I enter www.mywebsite.com from any android/iphone, it redirects automatically to mobile.mywebsite.com and displays page not found error. I dont have any mobile site developed for this. I want to show the main site even on the smartphones.

I am not good at .htaccess file, and I am using default .htaccess to remove the index.php in the url.

I tried creating a subdomain mobile.mywebsite.com and pointed to root path. But same response. I search online, but didnt find anything on how to STOP redirecting.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have u used hooks? I think u mite have used hooks for the sake of redirection, paste your hooks file.

Comment: I dont know about hooks until you mentioned it. I searched a little and I got the hook file under application/config/hooks.php.

It doesnt have any information it. It just has
    <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was uploading my local files into the server I was NOT overwriting the old ones assuming the folder is clean and no need to overwrite. But my hosting provider has default .htaccess which is redirecting to the mobile site.

I deleted the old one and gave my .htaccess without the mobile redirection and everything is in place now